# Add a column from one file into another file using AWK for a given condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

First of all, thank you for your help. I have 2 files which are

```
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   10
5   20
```

And

```
A   10
B   20
C   30
```

I wanto to filter both files using AWK so the if $2 in the first file is equal to the value of $2 in the second file the output will be adding a new column which matches the condition given:

```
 1  A   10  
 2  B   20  
 3  C   30
 4  A   10  
 5  B   20
```

I have tried this code:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' letters.txt numbers.txt >> combined.txt
```

The problem is that the code only replace one column for the other I want to that the column matches the condition I have given above. Also I want to put the new column between the columns from number.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
awk '
     NR == FNR { m[$2]=$1;   next }
     $2 in m   {    $3=m[$2]      }
     1
' letters.txt numbers.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much but do you how to put it in $2 in file 1 and displace $2 in file 1 to $3?